# convert passwordhash to password in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I am querying my database to get password. But I am getting passwordhash. Is there any way to convert it to string.

```
SELECT passwordhash FROM userTable WHERE userID = 21600
```

I dont have any field with password.

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of hashing do you use? MD5?

Answer (score 7):

If there was a way, that would mean that a broken hashing algorithm was in use. In other words, no, there is no way to go back from the hash to the original password.

The point is to generate a hash from the entered password, using the same algorithm, and compare it with the hash from the database. That way you can authenticate without compromising password security by storing them in the database.

Answer (score 5):

> I am querying my database to get password.

Then *either* you're going to fail *or* your system is insecure. You shouldn't be storing a password in a reversible form.

> But I am getting passwordhash.

Good! That suggests the system was designed securely.

The whole *point* of storing a password hash is to avoid storing the password itself in *any* form which can be reversed.

If someone hacks your system and gets all your private keys, I don't want them to be able to find out my password. If they just have the hash - and if the hashing algorithm has been chosen appropriately - then they shouldn't be able to get back to the original password from the hash, in a reasonable amount of time.

Equally it stops anyone trusted *in your system* from knowing the password, too. Bear in mind that people (unfortunately) reuse passwords. Company X doesn't want someone company Y logging in as one of their users, due to the password having been stored insecurely. (Unfortunately, too many places *do* store and even email plaintext passwords - but it should be discouraged.)

Fundamentally, you should be taking a step back - think about *why* you're trying to get the password, and what alternative approach you can take that doesn't require it. Changing the system so that you can *get* at a user's plaintext password should not be considered a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a hash, then the algorithm is one-way only, you can't get the original password back, except using [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) or some bruteforce tool.